# How can enclosing regexp in group change the result?

Tags: regex

On a string `'abbc'`

This regexp `/(.)\1*/g` gives 3 matches (`'a'`,`'bb'` and `'c'`).

Very similar regexp `/((.)\1*)/g` gives **4 matches** ((`'a'`,`'b'`, `'b'` and `'c'`).

I always assumed, that the outside group does not and can not change the result. How that is even possible?

See https://regex101.com/r/5fX9My/1

Comment: The outer group is group #1. _That_ is what makes the pattern different. To have an identical pattern with an extra outer group, you need `((.)\2*)`.

Comment: When you add the external group, you change the internal group to the second group, so you need to adjust your regex to `((.)\2*)`. https://regex101.com/r/5fX9My/2

Comment: Aaaargs. Yes, I am stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Your second pattern doesn't match the same as the first one. When you enclose your pattern in a *capturing* group, that group becomes group #1. So, in your first pattern, `\1` is a backreference for `(.)` while in the second pattern, `\1` is a backreference for the outer group.

To create a pattern that's identical to the first one but with an extra outer group, you should use:

```
((.)\2*)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8rLTu0/1).